# Deploying Umbraco 7.1 to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, umbraco

I created an Umbraco site with Visual Studio by creating an empty web project and installing the Umbraco 7.1 nuget package. During the set up portion, I created an Azure database. Next, I just created an azure website and deployed the code via Visual Studio publish.

Everything works fine on my local machine. The front end of the site seems to work fine on the azure website. However, I am not able to edit anything in back office. I can log in, but none of the button on the left hand side show up. See the attached screen shot.

[image]

This is my first experience with Umbraco so any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: What JavaScript errors do you get?

Comment: These are the errors I'm getting:

GET http://valentinesdaymassacre.azurewebsites.net/umbraco/Api/UpdateCheck/GetCheck 417 (Invalid token) angular.min.js:106
GET http://valentinesdaymassacre.azurewebsites.net/umbraco/UmbracoApi/Section/GetSections 417 (Invalid token) angular.min.js:106
GET http://valentinesdaymassacre.azurewebsites.net/umbraco/UmbracoApi/Dashboard/GetDashboard?section=content 417 (Invalid token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I feel stupid. All I had to do was clear my cookies and everything started working. I guess it wrote a cookie that it didn't like when I ran it locally. I don't see how it could even try to access the cookie via the live site.

Anyway, it's working fine now...